# How to make website loading screen last long enough for users to experience it

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, web

I'm trying to get users to actually see the loading screen that i have worked on. I would like it to last around 3-5 seconds JQuery is fine because its already in use and heres the code and a
I really don't know much Jquery so thats why im asking you guys any fix would help another note that this is going on a bakery website (Don't really know why you would need to know but yeah.) pic,

[image: part of animation rotation]

```html
<div class="center">
  <div class="wave"></div>
  <div class="wave"></div>
  <div class="wave"></div>
  <div class="wave"></div>
  <div class="wave"></div>
  <div class="wave"></div>
  <div class="wave"></div>
  <div class="wave"></div>
  <div class="wave"></div>
  <div class="wave"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(window).on("load",function(){
    $(".wave").fadeOut("slow");
    $(".center").fadeOut("slow");
  });

</script>

<style>
  .content{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  .bodY {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.center {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #000;
}
.wave {
  width: 5px;
  height: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, cyan, #fff);
  margin: 10px;
  animation: wave 1s linear infinite;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.wave:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 0.1s;
}
.wave:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}
.wave:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
}
.wave:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 0.4s;
}
.wave:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
.wave:nth-child(7) {
  animation-delay: 0.6s;
}
.wave:nth-child(8) {
  animation-delay: 0.7s;
}
.wave:nth-child(9) {
  animation-delay: 0.8s;
}
.wave:nth-child(10) {
  animation-delay: 0.9s;
}

@keyframes wave {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
}
</style>
```

I haven't really tried everything because yet again i don't know much Jquery but i'll pick out the Jquery part,

```js
$(window).on("load",function(){
    $(".wave").fadeOut("slow");
    $(".center").fadeOut("slow");
  });
```

Comment: `"slow"` is just a shorthand for `600` miliseconds, you can just replace that with a larger number if you want

Comment: ok @skara9 tysm

Comment: doesn't seem to display right any more options?

Comment: Idk what you mean by 'display right' - what's the issue?

Comment: Well when its loading you can scroll down and it shows the page and when its done loading the loading thing just disappears. It should be locked so you can;t scroll down or anything. Its really weird @skara9

Comment: Then just set the css on your card to `position: fixed; z-index: 1`

Comment: got it thank i will try

Answer (score 0):

You could use the animate function:

```
  (selector).animate({styles},speed,easing,callback)
```

The other solution is to use use your fade out code, but with set timeout function:

```
setTimeout(fadeOut, 5000);

function fadeOut(){
    $(".wave").fadeOut("slow");
    $(".center").fadeOut("slow");
}
```